# Verification Proof of Uniform Continuity using the definition

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

May you tell me if my proof is correct? Thank you so much!

The problem is:

***Use the definition to determine whether or not f(x)= x/(x+4) is uniformly continuous on [0,2)***

Here is the definition:

[image: Uniform Continuity Definition]

We need to prove that for all epsilons greater than 0 exists a delta that depends only on epsilon such that
absolute value of x/(x+4) - y/(y+4)
is less of all epsilons.

Using algebra is not hard to find that

absolute value of x/(x+4) - y/(y+4)

is equal to

4 (absolute value x-y)/ [(absolute value x+4)(absolute value y+4)].

Additionally,

(absolute value x+4)(absolute value y+4) is greater than 16 and less than 36, because y is element of the interval [0,2)

Therefore, we just need to prove that

4 (absolute value x-y) is less than 16 epsilons.

***Proof.***

***For all epsilons greater than 0, let pick a delta equal to 4 epsilons.
If 
absolute value of x-y is less than delta = 4 epsilons
then
absolute value of x/(x+4) - y/(y+4)
is smaller of all epsilons greater than 0.
For all y element of [0,2]
Then f(x) is uniformly continuous on that interval. Q.E.D.***

Comment: Is less than $16\epsilon$

Comment: @AbdallahHammam Thank you for your help! I fixed what you told me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is okay. Just the wording is little bit wonky. Better something like:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Define $\delta = 4\epsilon$. Then, for every $x,y\in[0,2)$ with $|x-y| < \delta$ it follows
$$ \left| \frac{x}{4+x} - \frac{y}{4+y} \right| \le \frac{4|x-y|}{16} < \frac{\delta}{4} = \epsilon. $$

Comment: Thank you for your honesty and fantastic help!